# I always get remote server returned: Not Found when executing httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone 8 application and when I try to perform httpwebrequest i get always Remote server returned error: Not Found but when y I debug the URI in fiddler 2 I get the right result.

```
El código de usuario no controló System.Net.WebException
HResult=-2146233079
Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
Source=System.Windows
StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at AplicacionMusical.BiographyPage.ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callBackResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__1b(Object state2)
   InnerException: System.Net.WebException
   HResult=-2146233079
   Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   Source=System.Windows
   StackTrace:
        at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
        at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   InnerException:
```

this is the source code that causes this error:

```
Uri targetUri = new Uri("http://192.168.x.x/apptfg/get_group_biography.php?nombre_grupo=" + groupname);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request);
```

and the code for ReadWebRequestCallback is :

```
        private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callBackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callBackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callBackResult);
            using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => DescriptionBox.Text = results);
            }

    }
```

I wonder for a little help as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you performing a `GET` when the server expects a `POST`? Or some other verb?

Comment: No i have detected that the WP8 device i have is not connected to the network.